# How can I use the XML parsed in another view than the view where I parsed the XML?

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, feed, nsxmlparser

I want to use the data parsed in my main view, the main view is a Navigation Table View Controller, and I want to use the data parsed in a detail View of each post of a feed. I don't know how I can do this, I need help. Thanks :)

***MasterViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property NSMutableArray *posts;
@property NSMutableString *currentStr;
@property NSMutableDictionary *currentDic;

@end
```

***MasterViewController.m***

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;

}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize currentDic, currentStr, posts;
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://devlabs.es/feeds/"];
    posts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSXMLParser *parserFeed = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parserFeed.delegate = self;
    [parserFeed parse];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        currentDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        currentStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentDic setValue:currentStr forKey:@"titulo"];
    } if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [currentDic setValue:currentStr forKey:@"link"];
    } if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [currentDic setValue:currentStr forKey:@"description"];
    } if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [posts addObject:currentDic];
    }

    currentStr = nil;

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (!currentStr) {
        currentStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    } else {
        [currentStr appendString:string];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [posts count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"titulo"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"description"];
    return cell;

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}


@end
```

***DetailViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@end
```

***DetailViewController.m***

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"


@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize descriptionLabel, titleLabel;

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {

    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: If you want to use one instance of the class in two controllers, you can easily make a class, which will have only one instance - singleton [link](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)
if you want something different, please specify your question.

Comment: Now it's resolved, I used a NSMutableDictionary called *objects, and inside this I selected with indexpath.row the array *posts. And next with a segue I selected in a another NSMutableDictionary on the Detail Class, the object *objects. Like this:                    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSMutableDictionary *object = posts[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];